# How can I get user_save() to update the nid instead of creating a vid?

Tags: nodes

I updated a node at [hook_user_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7)() with this node object:

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->nid = $f_node->nid;  // Updating
$node->title = 'TestT';
$node->type = 'employees';
$node->status = 1;        // Published?
$node->promote = 0;       // Display on front page?
$node->sticky = 0;        // Display top of page?
$node->field_employee_first_name['und'][0]['value'] = 'TestF';
$node->field_employee_last_name['und'][0]['value'] = 'TestL';
$node->field_employee_email['und'][0]['value'] = 'example@example.com';
node_save($node);
```

It executes without error but only my `node_revisions` (vid?) table is updated. The `node` table is untouched.

Am I missing something in the object that is keeping it from updating the node (nid) table?

Comment: Any reason that you are not loading (if you haven't already anyway) the original node and then update that object?

Comment: @Berdir That completely solved the issue too.  Seems when you try to overwrite instead of update it creates a VID instead of updating the initial NID.  Throw an answer in and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating a new object, you should simply update the node object you already seem to have (or load it first with node_load()), update it's properies and then save it.

Trying to save a node object that doesn't have all properties set will result in loosing those that aren't set and other issues like the one you're experiencing.